# Reason for equality definition in COQ and HOTT

Tags: equality, coq, homotopy-type-theory

In HOTT and also in COQ one cannot prove UIP, i.e.
\Prod_{p:a=a} p  = refl a

But one can prove:
\Prod_{p:a=a} (a,p)  = (a, refl a)

Why is this defined as it is?
Is it, because one wants to have a nice homotopy interpretation?
Or is there some natural, deeper reason for this definition?

Comment: Is there a proof for your second statement? (also the type where equality lives matters in this case)

Comment: It's here: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/talks/edinburgh-13.pdf on slide 11

Comment: OK, now it's clear that you are talking about `forall (A : Type) (a : A) (p : a = a) : (a ** p) = (a ** eq_refl a) :> {x | x = a}.`, where `Notation "( a ** b )" := (exist _ a b).`.

Comment: Apparently this question is not about using Coq per se, so I think you'll better off moving it to [cs.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today we know of a good reason for rejecting UIP: it is incompatible with the principle of univalence from homotopy type theory, which roughly says that isomorphic types can be identified.  However, as far as I am aware, the reason that Coq's equality does not validate UIP is mostly a historical accident inherited from one of its ancestors: Martin-Löf's intensional type theory, which predates HoTT by many years.

The behavior of equality in ITT was originally motivated by the desire to keep type checking decidable. This is possible in ITT because it requires us to explicitly mark every rewriting step in a proof.  (Formally, these rewriting steps correspond to the use of the equality eliminator `eq_rect` in Coq.)  By contrast, Martin-Löf designed another system called extensional type theory where rewriting is *implicit*: whenever two terms `a` and `b` are equal, in the sense that we can prove that `a = b`, they can be used interchangeably. This relies on an *equality reflection rule* which says that propositionally equal elements are also definitionally equal. Unfortunately, there is a price to pay for this convenience: type checking becomes undecidable.  Roughly speaking, the type-checking algorithm relies crucially on the explicit rewriting steps of ITT to guide its computation, whereas these hints are absent in ETT.

We can prove UIP easily in ETT because of the equality reflection rule; however, it was unknown for a long time whether UIP was provable in ITT. We had to wait until the 90's for the work of [Hofmann and Streicher](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/venedig.ps.gz), which showed that UIP cannot be proved in ITT by constructing a model where UIP is not valid.  (Check also these [slides](https://ncatlab.org/homotopytypetheory/files/HofmannDMV.pdf) by Hofmann, which explain the issue from a historic perspective.)

## Edit

This doesn' t mean that UIP is incompatible with decidable type checking: it was shown later that it can be derived in other decidable variants of Martin-Löf type theory (such as Agda), and it can be safely added as an axiom in a system like Coq.

Comment: It's possible to internalise axiom K and still have decidable typechecking (cf. Agda for instance)

Comment: @gallais Yes, that's true. I'll add a note on that, too.

Comment: This answer seems misleading... UIP/Axiom K is compatible with decidable type checking (as the EDIT says, but that seems to contradict the answer?), and inconsistent in HoTT. Is this meant to answer about why Coq does not support axiom K by default?

Comment: I think I vaguely remember seeing a proposal for Coq along the lines of: in typechecking the `return` clause of a `match` it would add `:=` style bindings, e.g. in `Definition UIP_refl := fun (A:Type) (x:A) (e:x=x) => match e as e' in (x=y) return (e' = eq_refl x) with | eq_refl => eq_refl (eq_refl x) end.` then it would have `y:=x : A` and `e':=e : x=y` added to the context in checking `e' = eq_refl x` which would then succeed.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, I tend to think of `a = a` as pi_1(A,a), i.e. the class of paths from a to itself modulo homotopy equivalence; whereas I think of `{ x:A | a = x }` as the universal covering space of A, i.e. paths from a to some other point of A modulo homotopy equivalence.  So, while pi_1(A,a) is often non-trivial, we do have that the universal covering space of A is contractible.

Comment: Hi Daniel, that was exactly my question. Was the definition motivated by the homotopy interpretation or not.

Comment: Rejecting UIP is necessary to the homotopy interpretation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927295/reason-for-equality-definition-in-coq-and-hott#comment99204450_46935242), so I strongly expect the accepted answer is not correct (while this might be plausible?).