# Why is UIP unprovable in Coq? Why does the match construct generalize types?

Tags: coq

UIP (and equivalents like axiom K) must be added axiomatically in Coq if it is desired:

```
uip : ∀ A (x y: A) (p q: x = y), p = q
```

This is surprising, since it appears obvious from the definition of equality, which only has one constructor. (This of course rests on the interpretation that an inductive definition in Coq captures all elements of its type).

When one tries to prove UIP, one gets stuck on the reflexive subcase:

```
uip_refl : ∀ A (x: A) (h: x = x), h = eq_refl x
```

We might hope the following term would be an appropriate proof term:

```
fun A (x: A) (h: x = x) =>
  match h as h0 in (_ = a) return (h0 = eq_refl x) with
    | eq_refl _ => eq_refl (eq_refl x)
  end
```

This fails because it is ill-typed. We know that `h: x = x`, but when we match on the term, we lose the reflexivity information and it is generalized to `h0: x = a`. As a result, our return type `h0 = eq_refl x` is ill-typed.

Why is it that the match construct generalizes our type here? Would a non-generalizing alternative be tractable?

Comment: Does this duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935242/6863749 ? tl;dr: you can still postulate UIP; or you might be looking for extensional type theory, which has undecidable type checking.

Comment: I don't believe my question duplicates the post you linked, as the latter does not address the behavior and limitations of the match construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would a non-generalizing alternative be tractable?

There is precedent for such a match. It is provided in readily available extensions of Coq (in `Program`; it's also an option in the [Equations](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/) plugin). Agda also typechecks pattern-matches in a similar manner (if `--with-K` is enabled, [which is the default](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/without-k.html)).

As you've shown, you can define UIP with it, so all the reasons for not adopting UIP carry over to not adopting that match. Conversely that match can be compiled to a term using UIP, as is done by Program and Equations.

I can't really explain why "generalization" makes a difference though. I would bet the answer is in Conor McBride's thesis.

Comment: Reading about the Equations extension and related work was very helpful. In particular, the papers [Equations: A Dependent Pattern-Matching Compiler](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14052-5_29) and [A New Elimination Rule for the Calculus of Inductive Constructions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-02444-3_3). 

To sum up my takeaways, the match construct considers only whole type families. Considering arbitrary subfamilies is difficult, but various extensions have been implemented/proposed to reason about certain subfamilies in a decidable way.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935242/6863749), the eliminator for equality in Coq inherits this behavior from intensional type theory, where it was introduced to keep type checking decidable. However, later people realized that it *is* possible to have an elimination principle for equality that validates axiom K without ruining decidability.  This is not implemented in Coq, but it is implemented in [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)):

```
module Test where

{- Equality type -}

data _≡_ {A : Set} (a : A) : A → Set where
  refl : a ≡ a

{- Proving K by pattern matching -}

K : {A : Set} → (a : A) → (p : a ≡ a) → p ≡ refl
K a refl = refl
```

(The equation for `K` is the moral equivalent of the `| eq_refl => ...` branch  in Coq.) I am not entirely sure how Agda checks this definition, but I have the impression that it does not require a generalization step as Coq does.